# How can I import bib File to Latex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm new to using Latex. I want to import File reference.bib to my File document.tex. Above is my Code

**reference.bib**

```
@article{lin1973,
   author = "Shen Lin and Brian W. Kernighan",
   title = "An Effective Heuristic Algorithm for the Travelling-Salesman Problem",
   journal = "Operations Research",
   volume = 21,
   year = 1973,
   pages = "498-516"
}
```

And here is my document.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
Blablabla happened because there was a need to cite \cite{lin1973}..
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

I just received : Blablabla happened because there was a need to cite ***?*** . Can anyone help me. Thanks in Advance ^^

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since your question is not about `biblatex` but about BibTeX, I have retagged your question.

Comment: See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864)

Comment: You probably just forgot to run BibTeX. The full run required for your example is `latex-bibtex-latex-latex`.

Answer (score 0):

First, take care of putting your `reference.bib` file in the same folder as your `document.tex` file. This is essential!

Also, as Manuel Weinkauf told in his comment, when compiling, ensure that you first run (`pdf`)`latex` once, then `bibtex` once, then again (`pdf`)`latex` at least once. (Some graphical user interfaces will do all of that by just clicking on one button, but I do not know if we are using one (and which).

Important notice: if you are using command-line interface, you shall run BibTeX on the *auxiliary* file, i.e. `document.aux`, which was generated by the first compilation (so the command is `bibtex document.aux`).

Then normally everything should work fine. In any case, one does not have to *import* the `*.bib` file to the `*.tex` file: these are just two different files, that you put in connexion by placing them in the same folder ;-)

Kind regards,
/Nancy-N